# Why I'm getting "Leave this page" message on reloading this page in IE?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've made a page and I've used JavaScript and PHP. Now this page works fine in my all desktop browsers except Internet Explorer. The problem is that when I open this page in IE and when I reload this page, I get this message:

Leave this page?

null

[Leave] [Cancel]

I think the **script** that is causing this problem is this:

```
window.onbeforeunload= function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("seendefault.php");
        });
    return null;
}
```

I've written this because I've to run a PHP file on closing the browser when my page is opened in it. Is there any replacement of above script or can I improve it and my PHP file executes successfully without any issue?

Comment: Why do you need the `return null;`? Would it still work if you removed it? Because if it works in Firefox etc. it should work without the `return null;`. Otherwise you can probably do this with the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API).

Comment: Generally if you need to try doing this in `onbeforeunload` it's too late to send data unless you actually return a string and let the dialog be displayed

Comment: @charlietfl: unless you're one of the 5 people left in existence who believe that blocking/synchronous AJAX requests are underrated and a great idee :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem no, that's not the point.

Comment: @charlietfl: sure it is. By default, AJAX requests are asynchronous. The `onbeforeunload` callback will return before the AJAX request receives its response. The OP is now cancelling the event regardless (which is horrible). An alternative would be to block use a blocking ajax request, and return _after_ the request has been made. Both scenarios are disgusting, I know, but who am I to say that nobody should try this?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the event callback only accepts string returned. Read the docs.

Comment: @charlietfl: That's why I commented on the answer (about `e.preventDefault`), and why the return value (if coming from the AJAX call) requires a blocking request

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem my interpretation is OP doesn't want to display the prompt dialog. What would `preventDefault` do? That makes no sense. Thus my case for being careful because unless you do use the prompt to block... the request may get aborted due to unload

Comment: Is it compulsory to return something in this eventhandler?

Answer (score 2):

You are just adding an event handler when the browser is quitting. So you should do it this way:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  $.post("seendefault.php");
  return false;
}
```

You cannot have an event handler inside an event handler. And it should be `return false` and not `return null`.

Comment: You might want to remove the return false. Why have it?

Comment: Technically, OP probably wants `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` which isn't quite the same as `return false` in vanillaJS, pedantic comment, I know...

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was about to do something like what [Elias](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1230836/elias-van-ootegem) just said. That's the reason.

Comment: Can only return string in onbeforeunload. Don't return anything if don't want dialog to display. IE will still not like `return false`. Concept is also flawed as request may not even be sent in all browsers

Comment: What do you mean by event handler inside an event handler? Where have I used it?